# Set default value if nothing is selected

Tags: meteor

The code below is expected to set headerLabel to "Select an Item" when the app first starts. Then once an item is selected, the headerLabel is expected to show the item name. I am able to get it to do the second parts but not the first. Thanks

```js
//---main_menu.js-----------------------
Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: [
    {menuItem: "task1"},
    {menuItem: "task2"},
    {menuItem: "task3"},
    {menuItem: "task4"},
    {menuItem: "task5"},
    {menuItem: "task6"},
    {menuItem: "task7"}
    ]
});

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(event){
    Session.set('selectedItem', $(event.currentTarget).data('value'));
  }
});

//---header.js-----------------------
Template.header.events({
  'click .mainMenu': function(){
    alert("show the main menu ");
  }
});

Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function(){
    var selected = Session.get('selectedItem');
    if (selected === "") {
      headerLabel: "Select an item";
    } else {
      return selected;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
//---main_menu.html--------------------
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem" data-value={{menuItem}}>
              <img src="/abc.png">
              {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
            </a>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>s
  </div>
</template>

//---header.html-----------------------
<template name="header">
  <h1>
    <button class="col-xs-2 mainMenu" type="button">&#9776;</button>
  </h1>
  <h3><label class="col-xs-8 text-center">{{headerLabel}}</label></h3>
  <h1>
    <button class="col-xs-2" type="button">&#8942;</button>
  </h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple actually:

```
<h3><label class="col-xs-8 text-center">{{#if headerLabel}}{{headerLabel}}{{else}}Default value{{/if}}</label></h3>
```

And in js code you can just do

```
Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function(){
    return Session.get('selectedItem');
  }
});
```